# Get the name of authenticated user and store it

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form in which you submit a "project". One of the field is "created by", but the user does not update this, it gets the name of the authenticated user in that moment and inserts it into the db.

I know how to retrieve the user's name, but the problem is that when I login with another user, then all the name change, because I store the name each time.
This is my project controller

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Project;
use App\Client;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProjectController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');

    }



    public function index()
    {
        return view('projects.index', [
            'project' => Project::all()
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        if (Auth::user()->role != 1){
            return redirect()->back();
        }else{

        return view('projects.create',[
            'project' => new Project,
            'client' => new Client
        ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $r)
    {

        $validatedData = $r->validate([
            'proj_title' => 'required|max:100',
            'client_id' => 'required',
            'proj_desc' => 'required',
        ]);



        $currentUser = Auth::user()->name;

        $r['created_by'] = $currentUser;



        $project = Project::create($r->all());
        return redirect('/projects')->with('store','');

    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Project  $project
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Project $project)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Project  $project
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Project $project)
    {
        return view('projects.edit', compact('project'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Project  $project
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $r, Project $project)
    {
        $project->update($r->all());
        return redirect('/projects')->with('update','');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Project  $project
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Project $project)
    {
        $project->delete();
        return redirect('/projects')->with('delete','');
    }
}
```

And this is my index

```
@section('content')

<div class="row"> 
    <div class="col">
@if (Auth::user()->role == 1)
    <a class="btn btn-success" href="/projects/create">Add Project</a>
@endif
</div>
<div class="col"></div>
<div class="col">
@if(session()->has('store'))
        <div class="alert alert-success mt-2" role="alert">
            <strong>Project created</strong>
        </div>
    @elseif(session()->has('update'))
        <div class="alert alert-success mt-2" role="alert">
            <strong>Project updated</strong>
        </div>
    @elseif(session()->has('delete'))
        <div class="alert alert-success mt-2" role="alert">
            <strong>Project deleted</strong>
        </div>
    @endif
    </div>
    </div>
<br>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Project Id</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Client Id</th>
            <th>Created by</th>
            <th>Created on</th>
            @if (Auth::user()->role==1)
            <th>Admin</th>
            @endif
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody class="">
        @foreach ($project as $project)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$project->proj_id}}</td>
            <td>{{$project->proj_title}}</td>
            <td>{{$project->proj_desc}}</td>
            <td>{{$project->client_id}}</td>
            <td>{{$project->Auth::user()->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$project->created_at}}</td>
            @if (Auth::user()->role==1)
            <td>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Action</button>                                                  
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{route('projects.edit',$project)}}">Edit</a>

                    <form method="POST" action="{{route('projects.destroy',$project)}}" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')">
                        @method('DELETE')
                        @csrf
                    <button class="dropdown-item" type="submit">Delete</button>
                    </form>
                 </div>
            </div>
            </td>
            @endif

        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>



@endsection
```

Comment: Have you tried anything before posting this question? Without any search and development you should not ask question here.

Comment: Why the name? Why not the `id`?

Comment: As I said I tried storing the name from the current user in a variable and inserting it. But my problem is that then it changes when another user logs in. Yes, I did research about this

Comment: @kerbholz Because I think is better to see the name of someone than the Id, which probably you don't know who it is

Comment: I'm with you, but (for relations) you usually save the `id` in your database and display the name when needed. So when someone changes their name the relation stays the same.

Comment: @kerbholz That's right, I'll work on that, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are using:

```
{{ $project->Auth::user()->name }}
```

instead of

```
{{ $project->created_by }}
```